# как вывести значения WaitForSeconds в unity c#

Tags: c#, unity3d

как показать отсчет времени при запуске/перезапуске сцены?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{
public Text timeLeft; // ссылка на текстовое поле, которое должно 
 //показывать, сколько времени осталось у игрока
public float startTime; // начальное время

void Start(){
    timeLeft.color = Color.white;
    startTime = 20f; //время, после которого сцена перезапускается
  //вызываю таймер
    StartCoroutine(ExecuteAfterTime(startTime));
}
//после 20 секунд (если игрок не успеет 
//за это время найти выход на следующую сцену) 
//текущая сцена загрузится заново и отсчет начнется заново
IEnumerator ExecuteAfterTime(float startTime){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(startTime);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
}
}
```

Comment: А почему вам не делать обычный таймер в `Update`?

Comment: пробовал, но при загрузке сцены, он не начинается заново, а остается на 0:00

Comment: Что то явно не правильно сделали. Если сцена перезагружается всё в нём работает с нуля и если работал первый раз то всегда работать будет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я использовал обычный таймер. Потому что в вашем примере нет необходимости использовать `WaitForSeconds()`.

---

## Работоспособность

Только в этом примере я использовал свой панель загрузки.

[image]

---

## Код

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

private void Start()
{
    maxTime = 3.0f;
    timeLeft = maxTime;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (timeLeft > 0.0f)
    {
        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;
        Timer.text = timeLeft.ToString("0");
    }
    else
    {
        DoSomething();
        timeLeft = maxTime;
    }
}

void DoSomething()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
}
```

---